# Karma Angular Testing - cannot call a method (that calls a Service) from component

Tags: angular, testing, karma-runner

I have a compoment (rooms.component) who calls a Service (RoomService).

In normal eviroment it works perfectly.

I can not test it using Karma.
As you see I can the method from the component from Karma, but the test Fails saying that rooms[] is undefined

At the beginning I had Problem with the route 
(It called non existing Service localhost:karmaport/api.......)

I solved using a Proxy in the Karma conf, but, even if I do not get 404 NOT FOUND anymore, the Service seems not to work (the Array is undefined)

I hope you can help me.

**rooms.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit }        from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { RoomService }              from '../services/room.service'
import { Room }                     from '../classes/room'

@Component({
  selector: 'rooms-component',
  templateUrl: './rooms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rooms.component.css']
})
export class RoomsComponent implements OnInit {

  rooms: Room[];

  constructor(
      private roomService: RoomService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRooms();
  }

  getRooms(): void {
    this.roomService.getRooms().then(rooms => this.rooms = rooms);
  }

}
```

**rooms.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RoomsComponent } from './rooms.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';
import { RoomService } from '../services/room.service';
import { TimetableService } from '../services/timetable.service';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';


describe('RoomsComponent', () => {
  let component: RoomsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RoomsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
    ],
      declarations: [ RoomsComponent ],
      providers: [
    RoomService,
    TimetableService,
  ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RoomsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be greter than 0', () => {
    component.getRooms()
    expect(component.rooms.length).toBeGreatherThan(10);
  });
});
```

**RoomService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { City } from '../classes/city';
import { Building } from '../classes/building';
import { Room } from '../classes/room';
import { Lecture } from '../classes/lecture';
import { FreeRoom } from '../classes/free-room';
import { TimetableService } from './timetable.service';

@Injectable()
export class RoomService {

  private apiUrl = 'api';  // URL to web api
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  lectures: Lecture[];
  constructor(private http: Http, private tmtblServ: TimetableService) { }

  getCities(): Promise<City[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/cities`)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json() as City[])
             .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getBuildings(): Promise<Building[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/buildings`)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json() as Building[])
             .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getRooms(): Promise<Room[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/rooms`)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json() as Room[])
             .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: `ngOnInit` is not called in testing environment. Also probably your promise has not resolved, when you check `rooms`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I found in your code,

1. You have made use of both Http and HttpClient, try just the HttpClient.
2. If you are testing a component, I dont see a point the you check the real response from the API. You can check the Angular documentation where they have suggested to use Mocked services for such cases.
3. For mocking you can do something like this,

This is required for mocking the service in HttpClient (not http) which can be used for mocking and fake response.

```
import { HttpTestingController, HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
```

then make use of HttpTestingController to mock the service, httpMock is the variable of type HttpTestingController,

```
const req = httpMock.expectOne('yourApiURL');
      expect(req.request.method).toBe("GET");
      req.flush(dummyResponse);
```

where dummyResponse should be like this,

```
const dummyResponse = [
        { login: 'Deepak' },
        { login: 'Deepak1' }
      ];
```

If your service is hit it would emit response which you have just setup in your testing configuration,